# AIR Printing Multiple Printjobs or addPage?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, printing, air

If I try to add ~70 High Resolution Sprites to a `PrintJob` using `addPage()` in a loop, I suffer a lot of slow down and performance issues.

I am thinking I should perhaps create individual print jobs for each page, or maybe batch them together.

What is the correct way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally push them into a data container prior to print.

Retrieve each job each tick. Allowing one job to finish quickly.

Push next job into processing.

Not using loops but perhaps dispatchEvents from a centralEventDispatchers.

Comment: Do you mean create the printjob, add a single page, send the job, and once complete repeat the process for the next page?